# 24 bit libfdk_aac audio with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, encoding

I would like to ask why ffmpeg's `libfdk_aac` encoder is automatically downsampling my audio's bit depth when encoding and I want to know how to stop it.

My encoding is as such (all data is there, except for metadata & file paths):

```
ffmpeg -i "/Path/To/Input.flac" -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 192k -ar 48000 -map_metadata -1 -metadata title="Title" -metadata artist="Artist" -metadata date="Date" "/Path/To/Output.m4a"
ffmpeg version 4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, flac, from '/Path/To/Input.flac':
  Duration: 00:31:31.71, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4721 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 192000 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (flac (native) -> aac (libfdk_aac))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, ipod, to '/Path/To/Output.m4a':
  Metadata:
    title           : Title
    artist          : Artist
    date            : Date
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (libfdk_aac) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 libfdk_aac
[NULL @ 0x7fb747801000] sample/frame number mismatch in adjacent frames
size=   44686kB time=00:31:31.71 bitrate= 193.5kbits/s speed=22.2x    
video:0kB audio:44338kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.784360%
```

No problems with encoding... (I simply encode to AAC, set bitrate to 192kbps, and downsample to 48000 kHz) except that for some reason, the bit depth is downsampled to 16 bit when encoding from a 24 bit source. I know the `libfdk_aac` encoder supports 24 bit, but for some reason, the encoder auto-downsamples. I have attempted to force 24 bit, with `-sample_fmt s32` but that returned with this error:

```
[libfdk_aac @ 0x7fc58100b200] Specified sample format s32 is invalid or not supported
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!
```

If anyone knows, I'd greatly appreciate a response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid not. The encoded output will decode to floating-point samples but the library only accepts 16-bit samples as *input*.

Comment: This answer is seemingly off topic; the question is **why** is the `libfdk_aac` encoder downsampling the bit depth to 16-bit and how do I solve it? I am aware that there is no issue with ffmpeg's built-in `aac` encoder. I just want to know if it's possible to encode 24-bit AAC with `libfdk_aac`.

Comment: FDK isn't downsampling anything - the library only accepts 16-bit PCM samples as input. What is unclear?

Comment: ffmpeg's command line is nicely confusing. But I've checked and it seems the file actually _is_ 24-bit. Thank you for your help.